# Looking for Web service standard to disseminate water level data

Tags: web-service, ogc, standards, waterways, sos

I’m about to lead a project that has to disseminate observed, forecasted and predicted water level data coming from tide gauges. I did a lot of research to identify which dissemination standards to support (Web Service). Many of the recommendations are pointing for the OGC SOS but it seems that it only does the observation dissemination part of our needs. No way to embed forecast and prediction and the transactional aspects are not adapted to support QA/QC advanced process.

So, I’m wondering if there are standards that exist or that are on their way to be adopted by OGC (such as SOS) but concerning the Water levels time series (observation, forecast and prediction). We have already looked at the SensorThingAPI. It could be an option but it is still not adopted by the community (at the time that I write this post).

Does anybody is aware of a Web service standard that can meet our needs?